# Java-class-file loader library in C

Tags: java, c

Can you tell me what is the meaning of " Java-class-file loader library in C"?

It's a homework assignment and I am not sure how I should approach it.

**Update:**
I just found out a link on [github](https://github.com/vegard/cafebabe) which exactly defines the topic but I still need some help to figure out what exactly this means?

Comment: If you post the full question, it may add a bit of context to help us out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose it's about a C library which provides an API for loading Java .class files. This should be possible using [JNI](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

A few ideas:

- Compare what is done during compile time and runtime for java and c.
- Compare the concepts of dynamic linking LD_LIBRARY_PATH and CLASSPATH

Answer (score 0):

It means that the library written in c is able to load java compiled classes, IOW java-class-files.